# Selecting Rails Models via Virtual Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes, virtual-attribute

I have the two rails models `Section` & `SectionRevision`. A Section is mostly just a container that holds all the Revisions relating to itself. So most of the attributes for the `Section` are basically stored within the `SectionRevision` model so there's a history of Revisions that can be reverted back to at any time.

Sometimes I need to access the attributes for the latest revision from the Sections Model so I've created some Virtual Attributes to account for this.

---

Each model has the attributes as defined in these migrations:

Section:

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sections do |t|
      t.integer "page_id", :null => false

      t.timestamps
      t.datetime "deleted_at"
    end
    add_index("sections", "page_id")
    add_index("sections", "current_revision_id")
  end
end
```

SectionRevision:

```
class CreateSectionRevisions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :section_revisions do |t|
      t.integer "section_id", :null => false
      t.integer "parent_section_id"

      t.integer "position"
      t.string "title", :default => "", :null => false
      t.text "body", :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
        add_index("section_revisions", "section_id")
        add_index("section_revisions", "parent_section_id")
  end
end
```

---

And the models:

SectionRevision:

```
class SectionRevision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section, :class_name => 'Section', :foreign_key => 'section_id'
  belongs_to :parent_section, :class_name => 'Section', :foreign_key => 'parent_section_id'

  def parsed_json
    return JSON.parse(self.body)
  end
end
```

Section:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', :foreign_key => 'section_id'
  has_many :references

  def current_revision
    self.revisions.order('created_at DESC').first
  end

  def position
    self.current_revision.position
  end

  def parent_section
    self.current_revision.parent_section
  end

  def children
    Sections.where(:parent_section => self.id)
  end
end
```

---

As you can see `Section` has a couple of virtual attributes like, `parent_section`,`current_revision` & `position`.

The problem being now I would like to create a virtual attribute, `children` that selects all sections where the virtual attribute `parent_section.id` is equal to `self.id`. Is this possible at all? I know the above code won't work as its doing a query for a column that doesn't exist - and I'm not sure how to access the Model instances from within the model 'Sections' doesn't appear to work.

Can a perform a selection based on virtual attributes?

---

I've updated the model based on  ProGNOMmers answer and get the following:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', 
                       :foreign_key => 'section_id'
 #Need to somehow modify :child_revisions to only be selected if it is the section_id's current_revision?
  has_many :child_revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', 
                             :foreign_key => 'parent_section_id'
  has_many :children, :through => :child_revisions, 
                      :source => :section
end
```

Circumstance 1: This works perfectly fine.

```
1.9.3p392 :040 > section
 => #<Section id: 3, page_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-02 01:31:42", updated_at: "2013-04-02 01:31:42", deleted_at: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :041 > sub_section
 => #<Section id: 4, page_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", updated_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", deleted_at: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :042 > revision1
 => #<SectionRevision id: 5, section_id: 4, title: "test", body: "[{\"type\":\"testbody\"}]", created_at: "2013-04-04 10:21:46", updated_at: "2013-04-04 21:55:10", position: 3, parent_section_id: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :043 > revision2
 => #<SectionRevision id: 6, section_id: 4, title: "test", body: "[{\"type\":\"testbody\"}]", created_at: "2013-04-04 12:29:19", updated_at: "2013-04-04 21:55:15", position: 3, parent_section_id: 3> 
1.9.3p392 :044 > sub_section.current_revision
  SectionRevision Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `section_revisions`.* FROM `section_revisions` WHERE `section_revisions`.`section_id` = 4 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<SectionRevision id: 6, section_id: 4, title: "test", body: "[{\"type\":\"testbody\"}]", created_at: "2013-04-04 12:29:19", updated_at: "2013-04-04 21:55:15", position: 3, parent_section_id: 3> 
1.9.3p392 :045 > section.children
 => [#<Section id: 4, page_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", updated_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", deleted_at: nil>]
```

Circumstance 2:

```
1.9.3p392 :021 > section
 => #<Section id: 3, page_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-02 01:31:42", updated_at: "2013-04-02 01:31:42", deleted_at: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :022 > sub_section
 => #<Section id: 4, page_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", updated_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", deleted_at: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :023 > revision1
 => #<SectionRevision id: 5, section_id: 4, title: "test", body: "[{\"type\":\"testbody\"}]", created_at: "2013-04-04 10:21:46", updated_at: "2013-04-04 10:24:22", position: 3, parent_section_id: 3> 
1.9.3p392 :024 > revision2
 => #<SectionRevision id: 6, section_id: 4, title: "test", body: "[{\"type\":\"testbody\"}]", created_at: "2013-04-04 12:29:19", updated_at: "2013-04-04 12:29:19", position: 3, parent_section_id: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :025 > sub_section.current_revision
  SectionRevision Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `section_revisions`.* FROM `section_revisions` WHERE `section_revisions`.`section_id` = 4 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<SectionRevision id: 6, section_id: 4, title: "test", body: "[{\"type\":\"testbody\"}]", created_at: "2013-04-04 12:29:19", updated_at: "2013-04-04 12:29:19", position: 3, parent_section_id: nil> 
1.9.3p392 :026 > section.children
  Section Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `sections`.* FROM `sections` INNER JOIN `section_revisions` ON `sections`.`id` = `section_revisions`.`section_id` WHERE `section_revisions`.`parent_section_id` = 3
 => [#<Section id: 4, page_id: 10, created_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", updated_at: "2013-04-04 10:19:33", deleted_at: nil>]
```

In circumstance 2 I would like `section.children` to return `=> []` as `sub_section.current_revision.parent_section_id = nil` and not `section.id`.

In other words `section.children` should return all `Sections` where `.current_revision.parent_section_id = section.id` but I can't query that as `.current_revision` is a virtual attribute.

Is it possible to maybe turn `Section.current_revision` in to some sort of association? Or maybe the only way is to add a `current_revision` column to the `sections table`?

Answer (score 3):

I think custom relationships are well suited for this cases:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', 
                       :foreign_key => 'section_id'
  has_many :child_revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', 
                             :foreign_key => 'parent_section_id'
  has_many :children, :through => :child_revisions, 
                      :source => :section
end

Section.find(42).children 
#=> SELECT ... WHERE ... AND section_revisions.parent_section = 42
```

I didn't tried the code, there could be mistakes, but the idea should be correct.

*I deleted the part about `:conditions`, since is not useful after the last edits*

Comment: Could you explain what `:conditions => proc` does?

Comment: I had to change it to `:conditions => proc{ { :parent_section_id => id } }` but I get an empty array in return. I've updated the question above with the details.

Comment: I updated the answer with more informations. An empty array should mean that there aren't revisions which match the conditions; check `children.to_sql`, in order to verify that the generated SQL is right

Comment: looking at your irb output `section_id` should not match (`s.section_id` is 3 and `sr.section_id` is 4); maybe the relation is wrong: try with `has_many :children, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', :foreign_key => 'parent_section_id'` (without `:conditions`)

Comment: Yes that works, but I would like it to return ss, that is sr's section_id - in other words find the `SectionRevision` that has `parent_section_id` that matches `self.id` and return the `Section` that matches it's `section_id`.

Comment: Maybe a :through association?

Comment: yes, something like `has_many :child_revisions, :class_name => 'SectionRevision', :foreign_key => 'parent_section_id'` and `has_many :children, :through => :child_revisions, :source => :section`

Comment: That works great but right now it `s.children` will return `ss` if it has any `SectionRevisions` that have a `parent_id` equal to `s.id`. What I would like is for it to return `ss` only if the latest `SectionRevision`(ss.current_revision) `parent_id` is equal to `s.id`. Is there some way we could do that? Sorry it's so complicated.

Comment: I didn't understand: do you want the section related to `current_revision`? or maybe the parent section related to it?

Comment: Section I think... Say `ss` has 2 `SectionRevisions`, `sr1` & `sr2` - `sr1` was created yesterday and `sr2` was created today. That would make `sr2` the `current_revision` as it is the latest record... If `sr2.parent_id` = 3 then `s.children` should return `ss`. However if `sr2.parent_id` = null and `sr1.parent_id` = 3 then `s.children` returns nothing as the `current_revision` doesn't have a `parent_id` that matches `s` - `sr1` is ignored because it is not the `current_revision`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should improve your model as ProGNOMmers stated; you could use some of following gems:

- ancestry ( http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry )
- awesome_nested_set ( https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set )

But answering your question literally, you can try adding 'children' method to your SectionRevision model and delegate Section#children to current_revision.

```
class SectionRevision
  def children
    SectionRevision.where(:parent_section => self.id) # parent_section IS a column of SectionRevision
  end
end

class Section
  def children
    current_revision.children
  end
end
```

BTW you could use #delegate for delegating:

```
class Section
  delegate :children, :position, :parent_section, to: :current_revision
  def current_revision
    Section.where(:parent_section => self.id)
  end
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't quite work as `:parent_section` is a virtual attribute in the `Section` and doesn't exist as a column that can be queried. I'll try improving the model as stated above althoughI don't full understand how `:conditions => proc` works.

Comment: I made a mistake - plz see my edit in SectionRevision#children